# How to make sure I have the contract proposal approval in my system?

Tags: database, web-development, database-design, relational-database, access-control

I am building a website and in it I am trying to follow the rbac (role-based access control) model.
Now, the thing is that managers need to send their contract proposals to approvers 
(people who will see if the company can go with the contract or not).

But, because I have the rbac model where the admin can create many roles, how can I
make sure that there will be users who will be approvers of contracts?

I was thinking of having an attribute called **is_approver** which could be checked when
the admin will be registering a new user if he is an approver.

Another possibility was to make the manager choose the users who should receive his contract 
proposal for approval. But then he would be able to send the contract proposal to users who
aren't even responsible for this.

How can I make sure there will be approvers in the system despite the rbac model and that the contract
proposal will be submitted to the right users?

Comment: Is your question "How do I make sure that at least one person has contract approval permissions?"  You can find that out by running a query on your RBAC database tables.  See below for a representative database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (simplified) database schema should look something like this:

[image]

So your Permission table will have an entry in it with a `PermissionType` of "Contract Approver".  You would then add records to the `Role_Permission` table to associate the "Contract Approver" record in the Permission table to each Role that should have Contract Approver permissions.

Comment: I'm guessing you got that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21254550/1493294). Are you sure the one-to-many relation between `Role_Permission` and `Permission` is pointed in the right direction?

Comment: @CandiedOrange: It's not.  Figures.

Comment: Oh yes. Now I understand where I was going wrong. I thought approver was a role and not a permission. But by making approve contract a permission, it totally makes sense. But now, would you recommend that when the users receive this system, it should be loaded with a few permissions in it already? Like contract approver. Because it's absolutely crucial.

Comment: Yes, you will pre-load the Permissions table with the set of permission types that you expect to use.